# How are html id attributes passed as an argument to a separate JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still new to programming. I've followed a tutorial for a JavaScript calculator online, and in this tutorial html id attributes are passed along to a separate JavaScript file. The file is passed as such:

```
<script src="logic.js"></script>
```

Here is an example:

```
var box = document.getElementById('display');

function addToScreen(x){
  box.value += x;

if (x == 'c') {
  box.value = ' ';
  }
}
```

Where the box variable is the empty field in a calculator where integers and operations are entered into (the 'c' is the button to clear the calculator). The function addToScreen has the parameter x, and x gets to be an input such as the number 9, which is entered with the following input:

```
<input type ="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick="addtoscreen('9')">
```

I'm trying to understand how these are passed more, so I'm playing with them. I have made a separate html and JavaScript file, and there are three input fields for the user to input numbers into, and a button to click to average the three numbers:

```
<form>
<input type="number" id="first"> <br>
<input type="number" id="second"><br>
<input type="number" id="third"><br>

Result: 
<input type="text" id="avgResult" disabled="true"> <br>
<input type="button" value="average" onclick="average()"><br>
</form>

<script src="logic.js"></script>
```

And the JavaScript file named logic.js has:

```
ar avgResult = document.getElementById("avgResult");

function average(a, b, c) {
  a = Number(document.getElementById("first"));
  b = Number(document.getElementById("second"));
  c = Number(document.getElementById("third"));
  avgResult.value = ((a + b + c) / 3);
}
```

Whatever combination of numbers I enter only results in NaN. I thought it would be useful to use the Number() method to convert any string to a number (I originally had the input tag's attribute set to "text", as opposed to "number".

Any advice or direction pointing would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

> `document.getElementById()` returns a DOM element.
>   Which means you are trying to convert a DOM element into a number, that's why the result is NaN (Not a Number).

**Solution:**

> What you need is a **value** of that element.
>   `document.getElementById("...").value` will **solve the issue**.

**P.S.**

1. Your `average` function doesn't need any arguments.
2. Put `let` before variables (a, b, and c) to correctly initialize them.
3. Don't use `<br>` tags for new lines, use CSS instead.

If you have any questions please put them below.